# DNS error - host not found after enabling site

Tags: wordpress, apache, sudo

I get the below error when I try and setup by wordpress site on Apache, `beta.xxx.co.uk`. Any ideas? I am expecting to see the wordpress setup wizard but just get an error.

I have:

- setup my A record in my DNS under my domain (beta).
- created my conf file under `sites-available`
- sudo a2ensite beta.xxxx.co.uk.conf
- ​sudo service apache2 restart

Conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName beta.xxx.co.uk
   DocumentRoot /var/www/beta.xxx.co.uk
   <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/beta.xxx.co.uk/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> Host Not Found
>   DNS error (the host name of the page you are looking for does not exist) or Server did not accept the connection.
>
> Please check that the host name has been spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

all I could find is:

```
<Directory /var/www/beta.xxx.co.uk/>
```

should propably be:

```
<Directory /var/www/beta.xxx.co.uk>
```

Port 80 & 443 is open?

Regards Tom